# Generate random matrix with every number 0..k

Tags: python, algorithm

Given an integer `k`, I am looking for a pythonic way to generate a `nxm` matrix (or nested list) which has every integer from `0..k-1` but no integer appears more than once in each row.

Currently I'm doing something like this

`random.sample(list(combinations(xrange(k), m)), n)`

but this does not guarantee every number from `0..k-1` is included, only that no integer appears more than once in each row. Also this has combinatorial complexity which is obviously undesirable.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it necessary for code to be short one-liner?

Comment: could you maybe give an example what your output should look like? i.e for a 4x4 matrix

Comment: It's unclear what you ask, should each row contain all numbers, what is the relation between `k`, `m` and `n`?

Comment: @CommuSoft The question seems perfectly clear to me.  `m <= k <= n*m`, each row will only contain some numbers but no duplicates, between all of the rows, all numbers have to be contained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to generate a random `n*m` matrix of integers `1..k` with every integer used, and no integer used twice in any row.  And you want to do it efficiently.

If you just want to generate a reasonable answer, reasonably quickly, you can generate the rows by taking a random selection of elements, and putting them into a random order.  numpy.random.random_sample and numpy.random.shuffle can do that.  You will avoid the duplicate element issue.  If you fail to use all of your elements, then what you can do is randomly "evolve" this towards a correct solution,  At every step identify all elements that are repeated more than once in the matrix, randomly select one, and convert it to an as yet unused integer from `1..k`.  This will not cause duplications within rows, and will in at most `k` steps give you a matrix of the desired form.

Odds are that this is a good enough answer for what you want, and is what you should do.  But it is imperfect - matrices of this form do not all happen with exactly equal probability.  (In particular ones with lots of elements only appearing once show up slightly more than they should.)  If you need a perfectly even distribution, then you're going to have to do a lot more work.

To get there you need a bit of theory.  If you have that theory, then you can understand the answer as, "Do a dynamic programming solution forwards to find a count of all possible solutions, then run that backwards making random decisions to identify a random solution."  Odds are that you don't have that theory.

I'm not going to give a detailed explanation of that theory.  I'll just outline what you do.

You start with the trivial statement, "There are `n!/(n-m)!` ways in which I could have a matrix with 1 row satisfying my condition using `m` of the `k` integers, and none which use more."

For `i` from `1..n`, for `j` from `m` to `k`, you figure out the count of ways in which you could build `i` rows using `j` of the `k` integers.  You ALSO keep track of how many of those ways came from which previous values for `j` for the previous row.  (You'll need that later.)  This step can be done in a double loop.

Note that the value in the table you just generated for `j=k` and `i=n` is the number of matrices that satisfy all of your conditions.  We'll build a random one from the bottom up.

First you generate a random row for the last row of your matrix - all are equally likely.

For each row until you get to the top, you use the table you built to randomly decide how many of the elements that you used in the last row you generated will never be used again.  Randomly decide which those elements will be.  Generate a random row from the integers that you are still using.

When you get to the top you'll have chosen a random matrix meeting your description, with no biases in how it was generated.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using numpy? This simple code using [numpy.random.shuffle](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.shuffle.html) will give you a random list containing integers 0 to k exactly once:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.random as npr

k = 7 # or whatever you like
thisrow = np.arange(k)
npr.shuffle(thisrow)
```

You can repeat this as many times as you like to get a matrix.

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.random as npr

k = 7 # row length
m = 23 # number of rows
mymatrix = np.zeros((m, k))

for i in range(m):
    mymatrix[i] = np.arange(k)
    npr.shuffle(mymatrix[i])
```

I agree with CommuSoft above that you have underspecified the relationships between `k`, `m`, and `n` in your question. A row that contains every integer `0..k-1` in random order exactly once has length `k`. Perhaps the example you gave fails to give every integer in the range because `n<k`?

Comment: See my comment above about what I think the problem is.  If that comment is correct, then you have not successfully solved it.

Comment: You're right @btilly. Bottom line is the question was not asked with enough specificity. Congrats I guess for guessing the intent correctly; is this an application you've seen before?

Comment: There was no guessing involved.  There is only one set of constraints that can be added to the stated question that makes it make sense, so it is reasonable to assume that that should be added.

Remember, people who have a problem usually state their problem correctly.  They just don't always include *everything* that is part of their thought process.  So it is better to assume that there is something missing than to interpret what was said in a random way.

Answer (score 1):

The efficiency of the following depends on the relative values of k, n and m, but if you know that `n*m` is much larger than `k`, it is probably as fast as you will get. It also has the virtues of simplicity and lack of bias:

```
from functools import reduce
from itertools import chain
from operator import ior
from random import sample

def gen(k,m,n):
  if m > k or k > m*n:
    raise ValueError("Unsatisfiable constraint")
  while True:
    mat = [sample(range(k), m) for i in range(n)]
    if reduce(ior, (1<<i for i in chain(*mat))) == (1<<k) - 1:
      yield mat
```

The generator `gen` repeatedly computes a list of `n` lists of length `m` where each member list is composed of unique elements of `range(k)` and until the `n*m` elements of the combined list include all elements of `range(k)`. Once that constraint is satisfied, the successful matrix is yielded, and the cycle continues on the next iteration.

It's possible that a large number of candidate matrices will need to be generated in order to find one which satisfies the constraint. In general, large values of `k` and `m` are bad. For example, with `k=10, n=4 and m=6`, it's rarely necessary to generate more than two matrices, and often the first one works. However, for `k=100, n=40, m=6`, hundreds of matrices are thrown away for every successful one, and for `k=100, n=4, m=60`, it takes tens of thousands of tries to find a compliant matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Take each number 1..k and assign it to a certain line of the matrix.

For each line of the matrix, fill the gaps without repetitions. Shuffle each line also to keep randomness.

It seems pretty straightforward and efficient.

Edit:

```
import random

k = 10
kset = set(range(k))
m = 4
n = 5

matrix = []
for i in range(m):
    matrix.append(set())

for i in range(k):
    matrix[random.randint(0,m-1)].add(i)

for i in range(m):
    presents = matrix[i]
    newelements = random.sample(kset-presents, n-len(presents))
    matrix[i] = random.sample( matrix[i] | set(newelements), n)
```